# AdvancedFilter not filtering the table

Tags: excel, vba, advanced-filter

I use a userform to search in an employee database and if found display the criterias.

userform:
[image]

Database:
[image]

Code:

```
    'filter the data
DataSH.Range("B8:E").CurrentRegion.AdvancedFilter _
Action:=xlFilterCopy, CriteriaRange:=DataSH.Range("$L$8:$L$9"), CopyToRange:=Range("$N$8:$Q$8"), Unique:=False
'add the dynamic data to the listbox
lstEmployee.RowSource = DataSH.Range("outdata").Address(external:=True)
'error handler
On Error GoTo 0
Exit Sub
errHandler:
'if error occurs then show me exactly where the error occurs
MsgBox "No match found for " & txtSearch.Text
'clear the listbox if no match is found
lstEmployee.RowSource = ""
Exit Sub
```

When I enter the name it sets L8 and L9 as the proper search criteria entered but always displays
"No match found for " & txtSearch.Text , meaning it doesn't filter properly the table

p.s credit to https://www.onlinepclearning.com/multi-page-userform-employee-database/ for the inspiration

Comment: `.Range("B8:E")` - that's not a valid range reference.

Comment: so simple...changing it to B8 solve it, thank you!

Comment: Inconsistent results, after changing it, it worked. Closed the userform and reopened it gives me "no match found"